# Как написать метод, который преобразовывает коллекцию из одного типа в другой (с помощью CollectionUtils.Transformer)?

Tags: java

Есть задача: нужно создать метод который перегоняет коллекцию из одного типа в другой, например:

Collection sample`в ->`Collection sample`.

Для единичного случая еще можно придумать, а как сделать чтобы из любого типа в любой другой?

Из библиотеки, указанной в названии, я нашел данный интерфейс, но как его реализовать не понимаю.

```
public interface Transformer<I, O> {
    O transform(I var1);
}
```

Пример обращения к предполагаемому методу:

```
Collection<String> colString = new ArrayList<>(); colString.add("1"); colString.add("2");

Collection<Integer> colInteger = CollectionUtils.transformer(
    colString, 
    new Transformer<String, Integer>() { 
        @Override 
        public Integer transform(String var1) { 
            return Integer.valueOf(var1); 
        } 
    }
);
```

Comment: ну интерфейс вы нашли, поищите его реализации

Comment: @Виктор, находил примеры, но там напрямую вставляют нужные классы, а проблема как сделать чтобы это работало в случае Object, Object.

Comment: Можете для примера привести сигнатуру метода и показать как он должен работать? Например, как будет преобразовано `Collection<Date>` в `Collection<Comparable>`?

Comment: Не любые типы совместимы. Если у меня в переменной типа String находится имя Вася, то как мне его преобразовать в Integer. Задайте корректные условия,а мы предложим решения...

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович, видимо я ошибся и не совсем корректно понял задание.
Как вы и написали нельзя создать универсальный tranformer.

Но есть пример. Как в данном случае написать метод transformer? В данном случае говорится про метод CollectionUtils.transformer() - 
CollectionUtils класс в котором я реализую данный метод
`Collection<String> colString = new ArrayList<>();
colString.add("1");
colString.add("2");`

Comment: `public interface Transformer<I, O> {
        O transform(I var1);
  }

 Collection<Integer> colInteger = CollectionUtils.transformer(colString,
 new Transformer<String, Integer>() {
     @Override
     public Integer transform(String var1) {
         return Integer.valueOf(var1);
     }
 });`

Comment: От Вас требуется написать свой метод или использовать [`CollectionUtils.transform`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#transform(java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections4.Transformer)) для преобразования?

Comment: @defaultlocale, написать свой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понял Вы хотите написать метод, который позволит пользователю преобразовывать коллекции из одного типа в другой, заданным пользователем способом.

Задачу может выполнить такой метод, который принимает от пользователя `Transformer` и возвращает список, в котором каждый элемент преобразован. Применить трансформер к коллекции можно с помощью [`Stream.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-):

```
public static <I,O> Collection<O> transform(Collection<I> source, Transformer<I,O> transformer) {
    return source.stream().map(transformer::transform).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

При вызове метода задается способ преобразования:

```
List<String> input = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
Collection<Integer> result = transform(input, (i) -> Integer.valueOf(i));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result.toArray())); //[1,2,3]
```

**Проблемы**:

- Метод принимает и возвращает интерфейс `Collection`. Коллекции могут быть переданы самые разные (`Set`, `List`, `Map`, собственные классы и т.п.). В текущей версии метод всегда возвращает список, это не очень хорошо, т.к. человек, который передает в метод `Set` ожидает, что возвращаемая коллекция будет соответствовать `Set` по поведению и производительности. Возможно, следует создать отдельные методы `transformList`, `transformSet` и т.д.
- Метод сразу считывает всю исходную коллекцию, это может быть ненужно если коллекция затем будет считываться частично. Следует рассмотреть возможность создания коллекции обертки.

Можете посмотреть пример реализации похожего метода [`Lists.transform`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform-java.util.List-com.google.common.base.Function-) в библиотеке Guava ([исходный код метода](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#line.524)).

Метод можно также реализовать без использования Stream API (например, если используется версия Java 7 или ниже):

```
public static <I,O> Collection<O> transform(Collection<I> source, Transformer<I,O> transformer) {
    ArrayList<O> result = new ArrayList<>(source.size());
    for(I element : source) {
        result.add(transformer.transform(element));
    }
    return result;
}
```

и использовать без лямбд:

```
Collection<String> colString = new ArrayList<>(); colString.add("1"); colString.add("2");
Collection<Integer> colInteger = transform(
    colString, 
    new Transformer<String, Integer>() { 
        @Override 
        public Integer transform(String var1) { 
            return Integer.valueOf(var1); 
        } 
    }
);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(colInteger.toArray())); //[1,2]
```

проблемы останутся те же.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, да именно то что искал вы тут описали. Пока я хочу реализовать в простом виде(через Collection), но да вы правы что это не правильно. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @sank Пожалуйста! Если вопрос решен, то [отметьте ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (слева должна быть серая галочка, ткните на нее).